# Etymology of "logical" vs. "arithmetic" shifts

Tags: bit-manipulation

I understand the difference between logical and arithmetic shifts. Why is each named the way it is? What is the history and context of those names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit shifts can be used to do the arithmetic operations of multiplying by two and dividing by two. For example, if you have five (101 in binary) and shift it left two bits (10100 in binary), the result is 20. So shifting left by *n* bits multiplies by 2<sup>*n*</sup>. Similarly, shifting right divides by 2<sup>*n*</sup> (with truncation).

In order for arithmetic shifts to work with negative numbers, you have to deal with the sign bit. In two’s complement notation, the high bit represents a negative value. For example, in 16-bit two’s complement, binary 1000 0000 0000 0000 (spaces for ease of counting) is −32,768. If we merely shift it right one bit, the result is 0100 0000 0000 0000, which is 16,384. That is positive, so we have not correctly divided by two. To fix this, an arithmetic shift duplicates the sign bit as it shifts. So the arithmetic right shift of 1000 0000 0000 0000 is 1100 0000 0000 0000, which is −16,384. Similarly, −20 is 1111 1111 1110 1100. An arithmetic shift right by two bits gives 1111 1111 1111 1011, which is −5. (However, note that arithmetic right shifts of negative numbers round results away from zero. For example, −3 shifted right two bits yields −1. So arithmetic shifts round toward −∞.)

With logical shifts, you are just working with the bits as bits. They are not binary numerals representing numbers. You might just be shifting bits to track some items left to process, with a 1 meaning some item that needs attention and a 0 meaning some item that does not. In this case, you do not want a high bit to generate extra 1 bits. These are called logical shifts because you are just using them for Boolean logic purposes—combinations of on and off and functions of them.

Wikipedia has pages on [arithmetic shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) and [logical shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift).

Comment: "With logical shifts, you are just working with the bits as bits. They are not binary numerals representing numbers." That's the key for me. Thanks!

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that an arithmetic right shift applied to 2's complement data is a division by 2**n with rounding to negative infinity.